# Error in using pdblp to extract data from bloomberg for my python code

Tags: python, bloomberg

I have written the code to try pdblp on my desktop where i have bloomberg installed as well. I am getting below error. Can someone help me resolve this issue

```
In [8]:import pdblp
con=pdblp.BCon(debug=True,port=8194,timeout=5000)
con.start

Out[8]:<bound method BCon.start of <pdblp.pdblp.BCon object at 0x00000178D754ECA0>>


In [9]:con.bdh('SPY US EQUITY','PX_LAST','20150629','20150630')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-33b8950f39e7> in <module>
----> 1 con.bdh('SPY US EQUITY','PX_LAST','20150629','20150630')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdblp\pdblp.py in bdh(self, tickers, flds, start_date, end_date, elms, ovrds, longdata)
    272         elms = list(elms)
    273 
--> 274         data = self._bdh_list(tickers, flds, start_date, end_date,
    275                               elms, ovrds)
    276 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdblp\pdblp.py in _bdh_list(self, tickers, flds, start_date, end_date, elms, ovrds)
    296         setvals.append(('endDate', end_date))
    297 
--> 298         request = self._create_req('HistoricalDataRequest', tickers, flds,
    299                                    ovrds, setvals)
    300         logger.info('Sending Request:\n{}'.format(request))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdblp\pdblp.py in _create_req(self, rtype, tickers, flds, ovrds, setvals)
    191             pass
    192 
--> 193         request = self.refDataService.createRequest(rtype)
    194         for t in tickers:
    195             request.getElement('securities').appendValue(t)

AttributeError: 'BCon' object has no attribute 'refDataService'
```

[Error message i am seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezb48.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the start method on your connection object.

```
con.start()
```